# Modify programmatically plugin parameters joomla

Tags: plugins, parameters, joomla

I would like to make a plugin that lets you use the google fonts. But I want the user to be able to choose from all fonts available. To do this I cannot use a static xml manifest for the menu but I need to create a updated list of the fonts in real time.

So how can I modify the plugin parameters programmatically? Is it also possible to use javascript to add some behavior to the menus for some ajax work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom element and add it to the plugin's `xml` file.

The following doc will let you know how to add custom element to a form.

You just need to change it according to your needs.

http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_a_multiple_item_select_list_parameter_type

This doc is just for example, you should be able to use this exact code, for example, you need not worry about saving the `params`. Joomla automatically saves the `params` of any plugin.

Comment: and for the adding javascript behavior?

Comment: You can add any html, any javascript in `fetchElement` function. And return whole html.